# Looping through files in an array and executing a command in IDL

Tags: idl-programming-language

I have an array with several files in it.  And i want to loop through these files.  For each file i want to run a command.

```
result = [rtlvis_20190518_13.35.48_00001.bin, rtlvis_20190518_13.35.48_00002.bin, rtlvis_20190518_13.35.48_00003.bin, rtlvis_20190518_13.35.48_00004.bin, rtlvis_20190518_13.35.48_00005.bin]
```

something like: for each file in result run the following command read_rtlvis_v12,a,c,t,g,FILE="file",/CFILEONLY
Where file is each one of the files in result

Ive tried the following

```
FOREACH file, result do begin read_rtlvis_v12,a,c,t,g,FILE="file",/CFILEONLY
```

The error i get is in the read_rtlvis_v12 code.  But my question is, is this the right way to go about doing a for loop with this kind of command.

Am i setting FILE="file" correctly, where file is each one of the files in result.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use quotes around "file" — that is trying to read a file literally named "file". Use:

```
foreach file, result do read_rtlvis_v12, a, c, t, g, FILE=file, /CFILEONLY
```